# Criar um executavel em c#

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e gostaria de saber se dá para criar um "executavel" como um programa externo, por exemplo: ao clicar em um button, usa o SaveFileDialog para salvar o "novo" programa.
Mais um exemplo: se uma { checkbox.checked = true; } o programa externo que eu estou criando, ao abrir, abre uma messagebox, mas eu não tenho a minima idéia de como criar esse programa externo .exe

Comment: #João_silva, você pode chamar uma aplicação externa com o comendo "Process.Start()". Você pode até passar parâmetros entre as duas aplicações.

Comment: Um executável de seu programa C# ? Comesse estudando o namespace [System.Reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.reflection?view=netframework-4.8) e dê enfase na classe [Assembly](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly?view=netframework-4.8) quando estiver dominando reflexão estude [DLR](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/dynamic-language-runtime-overview). Também é bom conhecer a [teoria dos compiladores](https://pt.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o_%C3%A0_Teoria_dos_Compiladores), .....

Comment: ... também é bom conhecer sobre [linguagem formal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linguagens-formais) e ferramentas como [gplex](https://github.com/dbremner/gplex) e o [GPPG](https://github.com/KommuSoft/Gardens-Point-Parser-Generator/tree/master/ParserGenerator)